# NSJSONSerialization not updating (possibly getting cached)

Tags: ios, iphone, json, swift

Hi I'm downloading JSON in my app to the device with NSJSONSerialization and it seems that when I update the JSON file and re-run the download JSON function it doesn't download the new JSON. It's just downloading the non updated JSON file. I've tried running the app on different devices and it works the first time but once I update the JSON again it doesn't download the new JSON. I'm thinking it may be getting cached but I'm not sure.

Here's my code:

```
func downloadJSON(){

    let p =  NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://themartini.co/pythonStuff/quotey.json")!)

    let sharedSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let dwn = sharedSession.dataTaskWithRequest(p, completionHandler: { (data : NSData!,re : NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            let js : AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil) as NSArray // downloads JSON and puuts it into an array

            println(js)



            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){

                self.quotes = js as NSArray

                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("dataTaskFinished", object: nil)

            }

        }

    })

    dwn.resume()

}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: ... and you've eliminated an intermediate CDN as the cause? How rapidly are you switching from device to device? The real fix would be to have your server supply the correct caching policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the correct cache policy to your `NSURLRequest`. There is an [alternative constructor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLRequest/initWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval:) that includes this parameter.

```
let p = NSURLRequest(URL: url, 
                     cachePolicy: ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData,
                     timeoutInterval: 15.0)
```

Comment: NSURLSession and NSURLConnection are equivalent for your task described above.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a cachebuster to your NSURLRequest. (change the url to  https://themartini.co/pythonStuff/quotey.json?23421231231

where the string of numbers at the end is random. This will break the cache. Also, instead of using NSURLSession, look into NSURLConnection.SendAsynchroniousRequest

Comment: Would I be changing the numbers at the end of the URL on the iOS side every time the JSON download function is called? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. That's the idea. Caches rely on URLs to return the same data. Also, hey there Yismo.

Comment: @Moshe So I would basically be randomly generating numbers and adding it to the URL? Also, Howdy!

Comment: @Moshe & Michael Voznesensky any reason why is better than NSURLSesion?

Comment: @Moshe any thoughts on the other answer?